# MissingMethodException when opening a form in the designer; runtime works fine

Tags: c#, forms, designer, missingmethodexception

Let's say I have a projoct A with a class A that has this property:

> ```
>     public bool IsConnected
>     {
>         get { return m_isConnected; }
>         private set { m_isConnected = value; }
>     }
> ```

In the same solution, I have a project B that references project A and has a user control called *Login*. This control has this attribute:

> ```
>     private A m_A = null;
> ```

and in the contructor of *Login* I do this call:

> if (m_A != null && m_A.IsConnected) {
>       ... }

In the same project, the main form has on it a user control A that was added with the form designer. The program runs fine and this property is correctly read.

However, when opening the main form in the Designer I get this execption:
MissingMethodException: 'Boolean A.get_IsConnected()'

Commenting out m_A.IsConnected let's me use the designer, but this is getting pretty annoying. And sometimes it seems like it randomly just works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Weird thing, I just found out that wrapping m_A.IsConnected into a method removes the exception (m_A != null always fails in the ctor):
private bool GetIsConnected() { return m_A.IsConnected; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been told in the past that this.DesignMode isn't always perfectly reliable.  The other option you can use is preprocessor directives:

```
#if DESIGN
return;
#else
if (m_A != null && m_A.IsConnected) { /* etc. */ }
#endif
```

Then add a conditional compilation symbol named DESIGN and you should be golden.

Comment: I'd love to fix the problem at its source, but I'll go for this workaround for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of commenting it out you could use:

```
if (this.DesignMode)
{
    return;
}
```

or

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
    if (m_A != null && m_A.IsConnected) { ... }
}
```

Edit:
I remember having problems with a singleton class once. Problem was that the singleton was always initialized although the constructor was never called. If I understand your problem correctly your problem is likewise. Your member m_A is never NULL although it should be.

I managed my problem with the following:

In Visual Studio go to "Tools\Options...\Debugging\General" and disable "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" and enable "Step over properties and operators (Managed only)".

Maybe that helps.

Comment: I was looking for something like this, thanks! Unfortunately, this workaround does not change anything, which is weird. I'll also add that at construction time m_A is always null so the IsConnected property should never be read anyways.

Comment: Remember to call InitializeComponents() first.

Comment: InitializeComponents() is called first, still get the exception even though !this.DesignMode and m_A != null should both fail.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Ari Roth DesignMode doesn't work right. To compensate for this, I use this extension method:

```
public static bool IsDesignTime(this Control control)
{
    if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (control.Site != null && control.Site.DesignMode)
    {
        return true;
    }

    var parent = control.Parent;
    while (parent != null)
    {
        if (parent.Site != null && parent.Site.DesignMode)
        {
            return true;
        }
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use it in the same manner that Simon Linder describes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the designer is using an old version of the control DLL, which does not have the IsConnected property.

The MissingMethodException exception is not related to the value of m_A. It is the JIT compiler complaining that the property is missing. If you wrap the call to m_A.IsConnected in a method, it works, because this method is not called (because m_A really is null), thus not jitted, thus the IsConnected property is not needed.

When you put the control in a form in VS, the designer creates a "real" instance of your control in the form, which calls the constructor, which causes the JIT compile problem.

Comment: Wrapping the call in a nother function works just as you say.  However I don't understand how the designer could use an old DLL, I did build and rebuild everything many many times...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't either. If you had an old version in the GAC, this would explain it, but it would not work at runtime either.
I guess you also left VS, deleted the obj and bin directories and re-launched VS.